# PollEvent() in Win32

Tags: windows, winapi, sfml

I'm trying to mimic SFML's [`PollEvent(Event &event)`](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.0/index.php) function in Windows. It seems far more complicated that I imagined. Note that I already encapsulated the window procedure function in my class.

There could be many "window events" in my program - `WindowMoved`, `WindowResized` etc.

My first attempt was to have a private data member in the class, defined as `WindowEvent *_lastWindowEvent`. This variable will be set if `PeekMessage()` returns a non-zero value, just before `DispatchMessage()` is called. Then, `winProc()` will edit `_lastWindowEvent`, depending on the message it will receive.
The drawback here is that I noticed that `winProc()` may be called with a MSG parameter regardless of `DispatchMessage()`, like with the `WM_SETCURSOR` message.

Then I thought about having instead a `std::queue<WindowEvent>` in my class, when `winProc()` continuously pushes `WindowEvent`s to it. The problem here is that sometimes the window procedure function keeps getting messages and won't return. This happens when I drag-move the window (then the `WM_MOVING` message is continuously called, along with other messages). The code after `DispatchMessage()` will not run until I release my mouse. This also happens when resizing the window.

Did I grasp anything wrong? How do you think such PollEvent function can be implemented?

Comment: [Replaying input is not the same as reprocessing it](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20121206-00/?p=5903). If you decide to break the contract, you'll wind up re-inventing Qt's broken-ness. Qt is broken beyond hope of regeneration. What you describe sounds a lot like Trolltech's, err, Digia's, no wait, The Qt Company's (that's what they are called this week) idea. Which turned out to be an abomination.

Comment: @IInspectable - Not sure what I just read. Can you explain further?

Comment: If you store window messages in your private queue and then later hand them off for processing, it will fail in subtle ways. The link above explains, why this fails for input messages. You have a single chance to handle messages (inside your window procedure). Don't waste it.

Comment: So truly wrapping win32 in a class, including the win procedure, is impossible?

Comment: Not at all, but you have to meet the requirements imposed by the messaging system. You can have the window procedure as a class member. From personal experience, though, it is best to keep the message loop out of the framework. Having the client implement its own message loop may seem unnecessarily cumbersome and error prone, but it does provide great flexibility. If a client decides to call `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects` instead of `GetMessage`, they expect the framework to not get in the way.

Comment: I see. So SFML and Qt are error prone? There doesn't seem to be a way to pass the window procedure from getting stuck until the user releases mouse drags. Also, what do you mean by `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects`?

Comment: I don't know SFML, but Qt on Windows is broken, due to the way it tries to abstract the message loop. It does replay window messages, causing all sorts of subtle errors. There are also *modal message loops*, that are out of reach. Whenever a modal dialog is displayed, or the user initiates a window sizing/moving operation, or opens a menu, or performs a drag and drop operation, the system uses a nested modal message loop. `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects` is a way to wait for either a message to arrive, or another object getting signaled. This is useful in multithreaded scenarios.

Answer (score -1):

Given that PollEvent is primarily for a game loop style design, you can probably poll for what you need while simultaneously servicing the Windows event loop:

```
class Window
{
    HWND _hwnd;           // Win32 handle to the window
    RECT _lastWindowSize; // last known window size
    POINT _lastMousePos;  // last known mouse position on window
    BYTE _lastKeyboardState[256]; // last known key state

    std::list<Event> _events; // unprocessed events

public:
    bool PollEvent(Event* pEvent);
};


bool Window::PollEvent(Event* pEvent)
{

   // return any previously queued events
   if (_events.size() > 0)
   {
        *pEvent = _events.pop_front();
        return true;
   }

   // process 1 windows event message
   if (PeekMessage(&msg, _hWnd, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
   {
       TranslateMessage(&msg);
       DispatchMessage(&msg);

       if (msg.msg == WM_QUIT)
       { 
           *pEvent = EXIT_EVENT; // special handling for WM_QUIT
           return true;
       }
   }

   // -----------------------------------------
   // poll keyboard state
   BYTE kbState[256];
   GetKeyboardState(kbState);
   bool isKeyboardEvent = false;
   if (memcmp(_lastKeyboardState, kbState, 256) != 0)
   {
        // not shown
        // compute diff of kbState and _lastKeyboardState
        // generate a keyboard event and add to the queue

        Event kbevt;
        kbevt.type = KeyEvent;
        kbevt.code = <computed code based on diff above>
        _events.push_back(kbevt);
   }
   memcpy(_lastKeyboardState, kbState, 256);
   // -----------------------------------------

   // -----------------------------------------
   // poll window size changes
   RECT rectWindowSize;
   int width, height, oldwidth, oldheight;
   GetClientRect(&rectWindowSize);
   width = rectWindowSize.right - rectWindowSize.left;
   height = rectWindowSize.bottom - rectWindowSize.top;
   oldwidth = _lastWindowSize.right - _lastWindowSize.left;
   oldheight = _lastWindowSize.bottom - _lastWindowSize.top;
   if ((width != oldwidth) || (height != oldheight))
   {
       Event sizeEvent;
       sizeEvent.type = SizeEvent;
       sizeEvent.width = width;
       sizeEvent.height = height;
       _events.push_back(kbevt);
   }
   _lastWindowSize = rectWindowSize;
   // -----------------------------------------

   // not shown - computing mouse position, joystick position, text stuff


   // if at least one event was queued - return it now
   if (_events.size() > 0)
   {
        *pEvent = _events.pop_front();
        return true;
   }

   return false;

}
```

Comment: Where's the window procedure function in all this?

Comment: @Pilpel - Do you know how to define a basic WndProc function and associate it with a C++ class? If not, I can show you how to implement this.

Comment: This doesn't address the second problem I noted. If the user will drag and move the window around, the queue will be flooded with thousands of messages until the user releases his mouse button

Comment: @Pilpel - your question was vague to begin with and you didn't post any code of what you had tried. So I assumed it was a design issue you were seeking help with.  I haven't observed DispatchMessage blocking on mouse down, so I'd need to see some code (shared by you) to assess the issue.

Comment: Also, I never understood what you meant by "mimic SFML's PollEvent".  Does that mean you aren't using SFML?  Or you are trying do something similar?  Or you are trying to extend SFML with your own event loop?

Comment: I'm not using SFML. I'm trying to build a framework that uses the same PollEvent()-like function. I'm sorry if my question was misunderstood